# 4nec2: What does "#12/in" mean?

Tags: antenna-modeling

I've been seeing this `#nnn` pattern in `SY` cards a few times, but I can't find any mention of it in the documentation. I'm guessing it's an AWG specification, but then I see something like this:

```
SY D = #12/in
```

So maybe `#12` specifies 12 AWG in `m` and `#12/in` is the same in `in`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the wire gauges like `#12` etc. are just predefined symbols that are the radius of that (AWG) gauge of wire, given in metric.

If you're using a GS card to specify dimensions in inches, then you need to divide by `in` to convert those predefined wire radii to inches — and then the geometry transformation will turn them back to meters, along with everything else, after the whole deck is read in.

`mm`, `cm`, `in`, and `ft` are also predefined symbols that equal the length of that unit in meters (i.e. 0.001, 0.01, 0.0254, 0.3048).